# Detect state of key even with hook installed?

Tags: c#, winapi, keyboard-hook

I have a situation where a third party program is installing a global keyboard hook, where it ignores specific keys. I need to handle detection of the keys pressed anyway, no matter how bad the practice may be.

I tried the following:

- Making use of the `RegisterHotkey` function - here, the callback never gets called although I press the key in question.
- Making use of a timer which keeps polling and asking `Keyboard.IsKeyDown` for the specific key - here, the result is `false` even though the key is down.

In all of the above scenarios, the third party hook still somehow overrules and makes my code return a false positive.

So my question is: **Is it possible to (with the use of polling or some other funky way) get the state of a key, even though a low level keyboard hook is blocking that key?**

Comment: Install your own LL hook then start the other process? The first hook in the chain is serviced first.

Comment: Are you sure it is not the other way around? I always thought the latest installed is the one that has precedence.

Comment: @AlexK.: From [Hooks Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959.aspx): *"The [**SetWindowsHookEx**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) function always installs a hook procedure at the beginning of a hook chain."*

Comment: I've faced this same situation before and solved it by hooking the third party program and hooking its hook (think detours). It's like inception with hooks. It works reliably.

Comment: Hmm @parrowdice are you saying that I can also install a low level hook into another process somehow? And can that still be done with C#?

Comment: @AlexK that's what I am talking about. If I install a hook, that one will be serviced first. Then if the third party process starts, its hook will be serviced first.

Comment: It looks like [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) is C++ only, but [EasyHook](https://easyhook.github.io/) can use C#. Basically, you hook the actual API call in the 3rd party process, so you can effectively 'stop' the other process from calling `SetWindowsHookEx` all together (or modify its call to suit your needs).

Comment: What about the Raw Input APIs? Can I continuously poll for raw input even though a hook is blocking the key?

Comment: Also @parrowdice if you can write an answer with how to use EasyHook or lead me in the right direction to accomplish what you described, I will mark it as answer and vote it up.